# GRAILS URL parameters short form

Tags: url, post, grails, groovy, parameters

I know that in GRAILS/GROOVY

```
def content=urlrestservicestring.toURL().getBytes(requestProperties: ['User-Accepted': username])
```

is a short form to have all the byte content (for example for PDF donwload), but I don't know all the request properties available for URL for richer connections, for example for POST method (this is a GET call) with payload in json. Is it possible? In which way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like per `requestProperties` you can set request headers only which might help for simple cases.

On the other hand if you want to do something more complex, like a POST, you have to use a propper HTTP-client.

In Groovy there's an idiomatic [HTTPBuilder](https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/) which is very straight-forward and easy to use, or Grails own [RESTBuilder](https://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder)

UPDATE:

Using HTTPBuilder the download could look like:

```
import static groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder.configure

configure {
    request.uri = "http://example.org/download"
    request.contentType = 'application/json'
}.post {
    request.headers.username = 'Scarpanti'
    request.body = [ some:'json' ]
    
    Download.toStream delegate, response.outputStream // from grails
//  or
//  Download.toStream delegate, file
}
```

see also [ref-doc](https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/asciidoc/html5/#_download_file_get)

Comment: Well I know RestBuilder but its response.body.bytes cannot give me a correct pdf, but always pdf with all blank pages, as if it was a char encoding or some thing like that, viceversa url.getBytes preserves all data correctly

Comment: I didn't use RestBuilder much, but pretty sure that HttpBuilder would do the job. If you provide the connection info, it should be easy to come up with some code

Comment: I need an username in header and a simple json payload as body of the POST and catching the response as byte of a PDF to be donwloaded into a browser afterwards,